# How to force to resolve async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm using `Sails.js` to build my API, so, as part of sails, to retrieve models I can override or modify the `customToJSON` method. Bassically this is the problem, `customToJSON` method is a sync method, but I´m performing some async actions inside. There is my code:

```
async customToJSON() {
  // set the interpolate characteres to `{{` and `}}`
  _.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g;
  const NOTIFICATION_TYPE = notificationTypes[this.type];

  // --->>> THIS IS THE ASYNC METHOD <<<---
  const templateParams = await Notification._getTemplateParams(this);

  // compile templates
  const compiledLink = _.template(
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE.link, { imports: templateParams }
  );
  const compiledTitle = _.template(
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE.title, { imports: templateParams }
  );
  const compiledDescription = _.template(
    NOTIFICATION_TYPE.description, { imports: templateParams }
  );

  return {
    ..._.omit(this, ['relatedModels']),
    _params: templateParams,
    link: compiledLink(templateParams),
    title: compiledTitle(templateParams),
    description: compiledDescription({}),
  }
},
```

It does not work, because sails is designed to run this method as *sync*. So the question is: Is there any way to force resolve a promise?

Im using `node v8.10` and `sails v1` with `action2`

Comment: Please add the version of node you are running this on.

Comment: Also: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/actions-and-controllers

Comment: @ethane I´ve edited my question, please check

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Sails documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson) :

> Currently the customToJSON function does not support async
>   capabilities.

(click on the link for more details)

So you can't have asynchronous code inside your `customToJSON`. Instead, you should call your `Notification._getTemplateParams` function before.

Comment: On my question I said it. I know that `customToJSON` does not support it, if you read my question I'm questing about a way to force resolve a promise

Comment: You can't force to resolve a promise. It does not make sense. The only way to have the resolved value is to wait for it. That's why I suggest preloading your data from `Notification._getTemplateParams` elsewhere. It seems you don't have the choice.

Comment: Actually I'm doing something like this: `await Notification.customToJSON.bind(notification)()`

Comment: I don't follow you.